# Add filter multiple times using only one master function

Tags: php, filters, templates

Is it possible to use add_filter with lets say an array of different values?

to achieve something like the following:

```
foreach($templates as $name) {
    add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template ) {

         global $post;

         if ($post->post_type == $name) {
              $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $name . '.php';
         }
         return $template;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `use` statement:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template ) use ( $name ) {
```

Or just pass all templates at once, and create just one function:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $file ) use ( $templates ) {

     global $post;

     if ( in_array ( $post->post_type, $templates ) )
          return __DIR__ . "/{$post->post_type}.php";

     return $file;
});
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, thank you so much! Haven't come across "use" in my PHP endeavors yet. I'm going to go read up on it.